Is a regular tempered distribution $T_u$ radial if $u$ is radial?
Let $u\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and radial function, i.e, $u(Rx)=u(x)$ for all rotation $R\in O(n)$ (the orthogonal group). Is the tempered distribution $T_u(\varphi)=\int u(x)\varphi(x)\,dx$ radial? (A tempered distribution is radial if $R(T)=T$ where $(R(T),\varphi)=(T,R^{-1}(\varphi))$ and $R^{-1}(\varphi)(x):=\varphi(R(x))$, $\varphi$ Schwartz function.
My attempt:
\begin{align}
(R(T_u),\varphi)&=(T_u,R^{-1}(\varphi))\\
&=\int u(x)\varphi(R(x))\,dx\\
&=\int u(R^{-1}(y))\varphi(y)\, d(R^{-1}y)\\
&=\int u(y)\varphi(y)\, d(R^{-1}y)
\end{align}
but $d(R^{-1}y)=dy$?
Thanks.

Remember that $R\in SO(\mathbb R^n)$ so $\det(R)=\det(R^{-1})=1.$ Therefore,
$$
d(R^{-1}y)
= \det(R^{-1}) \, dy
= dy.
$$

Thank you. But shouldn't this affect the definition of radial distribution? I understand that the definition is with the orthogonal group and not with the special orthogonal group (those with determinant equal to 1).

@eraldcoil. You are correct. The formula is actually $d(R^y)=|\det(R)|dy$ (if we treat $dy$ as a measure). You can look at what happens when we set $x=-y$ in an integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x),dx.$
